# Azure Event hub - "ErrorCode":"Forbidden","ErrorMessage":"SubCode=40300. The maximum number of resources of type EventHub has been reached or exceeded

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have generated logs from inside an Event Hub namespace by running the below query inside the blade 'logs'

`search * 
| top 500 by TimeGenerated // return the latest 500 results`

I am seeing errors generated with the below message:

> EventName - Create EventHub
>   Status - failed

```
{
    "SubscriptionId": "xxx",
    "Namespace": "xxx",
    "Via": "https://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/insights-logs-operationallogs/?api-version=2015-01",
    "TrackingId": "1d098e8e-24e0-47c8-aa64-49245474cc27_xx",
    "ErrorCode": "Forbidden",
    "ErrorMessage":"SubCode=40300. The maximum number of resources of type EventHub has been reached or exceeded. Actual: 10, Max allowed: 10. TrackingId: 1d098e8e-24e0-47c8-aa64-49245474cc27_xx, SystemTracker:xxx.servicebus.windows.net:insights-logs-operationallogs, Timestamp: 2020-01-07T10: 55: 03"
}
```

We are unable to find which process is trying to create a New Event hub. As far as we know there is nothing running.

I am not sure where to go and check.

Comment: Looks like there _is_ something running somewhere, creating an Event Hub. The [Resource Manager Exceptions](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/event-hubs/resource-manager-exceptions.md) also lists `40300` as 'The namespace has reached its quota for the number of Event Hubs it can contain.' Are you sure there's not something deploying ARM templates somewhere? Also: take the TrackingID and have a look in the operational logs.

Answer (score 0):

One of your resources is streaming diagnostics logs to Event Hubs and the destination Event Hubs namespace seems already has 10 hubs under it which is the limit, thus new hub create call is failing. If you are provisioning new resources check your ARM template and find Event Hubs dependencies there. Once found, you need to change it to another namespace which has room for new hubs.

See for more details on streaming diagnostics to EH here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/stream-monitoring-data-event-hubs